# Android app closes after .click() command

Tags: java, selenium, automation, appium

I'm trying to automate a app to do everything that you would have to do by hand. My main goal right now is to get it to click a button after logging into the app.

This is the very last line of code in my IDE
`driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/main_text")).click();`

**After this line of code executes, OfferUp, the app that I'm testing on, closes.** There are no failures in console but, **I don't want it to close after that line of code executes.**

When I log into the app without running my code, the app stays open but, when I run my code, it closes after `driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/main_text")).click();` is executed.

Why this is happening?

Here is my full code -

```
package OpenOfferUpTest;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.FindElement;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;

public class OpenOfferUp {

AndroidDriver driver;


@Test
public void OpensOfferUp() throws MalformedURLException
{
  File OfferUp = new File("C:\\Users\\boung\\Desktop\\OfferUp.apk");
  DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
  cap.setCapability("deviceName", "Virtual Device");
  cap.setCapability("platformName", "android");
  cap.setCapability("null", "OfferUp");
  cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.offerup");
  cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.offerup.android.login.splash.LoginSplashActivity");

  driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), cap);

}

@Test
public void SimpleTest() throws InterruptedException {

  driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/email_button")).click();

  By path = By.xpath("//*[@text='Enter your email address']");

  driver.findElement(path).sendKeys("sourgta@gmail.com");

  driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/next_button")).click();

  By path1 = By.xpath("//*[@text='']");

  driver.findElement(path1).sendKeys("12manytimes");

  driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/main_text")).click(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post your test class code so that we could help you better

Comment: okay there you go

Comment: Did you check your appium server log?